# React Native app crashing on Proguard Enable

Tags: react-native, debugging, proguard

I have a React-Native app which is working perfectly fine on debug. But the app doesn't open on release build.

Disabling proguard fixes the issue. So I started looking installation documentation for each third party package installed and my proguard rules seemed fine. Sadly I couldn't detect which package is creating the issue.

My question is : **how can I detect which third party package is causing this issue** ?

***Dependencies :***

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.1.5",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "ky": "^0.28.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-auto-height-image": "^3.2.4",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.0",
    "react-native-immersive-mode": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.29.4",
    "react-native-mmkv": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.9",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.2",
    "react-query": "^3.34.5"
  },
}
```

***Proguard Rules***

```
-keep class com.facebook.hermes.unicode.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.jni.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.turbomodule.** { *; }
```

Comment: Seems like a straight, in your face question to ask, but WHY are you enabling proguard at first place? I almost never enable Proguard ever.

Comment: @DNA.h . Enabling proguard reduces the app size, In my case disabing Proguard is Ok as app size is very less. However I wanted if I can detect which third party lib is causing this.

Comment: Also, I am not asking to look into my dependencies and find the root. I am asking how to debug this. Instead of checking docs for all of them (which I already did)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the release build and find errors in the console.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#testing-the-release-build-of-your-app

Comment: found it, reanimated was creating the [issue](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/2727)

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem and after some debugging and trying different solutions.
I had to add all these rules in file /android/app/proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.swmansion.reanimated.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.hermes.unicode.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.jni.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.turbomodule.** { *; }
-keep public class com.horcrux.svg.** {*;}
```

Especially last one is most common that most people face problem with.
Just add it if you are using any kind SVGs in your app.